# Не удается получить "Имя хоста" в локальной сети

Tags: java

```
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.3");
    String host = addr.getHostAddress();
    System.out.println(host);

    InetAddress addr2 = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("Local HostAddress:  "+addr2.getHostAddress());
    String hostname = addr2.getHostName();
    System.out.println("Local host name: "+hostname);
```

Пытаюсь получить имя устройства в локальной сети "смартфон андроид" по ip адресу но ничего не выходит.
Второй же блок кода удачно выдает имя моего компьютера с которого запускаю код.
Подскажите так ли это делается или же нужен иной подход?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации

> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is first
> called with the hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the
> operation is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, it will return
> the textual representation of the IP address.
>
> Returns: the host name for this IP address, or if the operation is not
> allowed by the security check, the textual representation of the IP
> address.

Вам вернется имя в случае отсутствия ограничений со стороны security manager.

```
try {
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.251");
      String host = addr.getHostAddress();
      System.out.println(host); //192.168.2.251
      String hostname = addr.getHostName();
      System.out.println("Local host name: " + hostname); //Local host name: WIN-USUUHLKQ03V
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

попробовал так

```
try {
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("64.233.164.101");
      String host = addr.getHostAddress();
      System.out.println(host); // 64.233.164.101
      String hostname = addr.getHostName();
      System.out.println("Local host name: " + hostname); // Local host name: lf-in-f101.1e100.net
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

что интересно в таком случае мне выдаёт

```
try {
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.100");
      String host = addr.getHostAddress();
      System.out.println(host); // 192.168.2.100
      String hostname = addr.getHostName();
      System.out.println("Local host name: " + hostname); // Local host name: 192.168.2.100
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

и на случай не существующего адреса аналогичный результат.

Comment: А security manager это что такое, служба на стороне хоста или метод проверки из java? Просто множество приложений как десктопных так и мобильных делают подобный запрос и успешно получают информацию, мне не известен протокол по которому передаются имена устройств или хоть что-то для идентификации их в локальной сети

Comment: SecurityManager sec = System.getSecurityManager();
                    if (sec != null) {
                        sec.checkConnect(host, -1);
                    }

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getsecuritymanager.htm

Comment: sec.checkConnect делает проверку? а как получить вывод?

Comment: sec.checkConnect(host, -1)

Comment: я не очень понимаю) но у меня пустой вывод, ничего нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116098/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-jonathan).